# How to get top 'n' percentage values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
col1    col2
b   5
b   10
b   20
b   30
b   200
b   300
```

select top 50 percentage col2 from mytable is giving

```
col2
5
10
20
```

Whereas actual 50% is different

```
col1 col2   Total(of col2)   div(col2/total)    CumulativeAddition  %
b   5           565                 0.01            0.01            1%
b   10          565                 0.02            0.03            3%
b   20          565                 0.04            0.06            6%
b   30          565                 0.05            0.12            12%
b   200         565                 0.35            0.47            47%
b   300         565                 0.53            1.00            100%
```

As you can see it is

```
5   1%
10  3%
20  6%
30  12%
200 47%
```

Am I using right SQL function?

Comment: `TOP 50 PERCENT` will just give you the top 50% **rows**. i.e. 3 out of 6.

Comment: I think top 50 percentage returns 50 percent of the rows.  I take it thats not what you want?

Comment: @MartinSmith that should be an answer

Comment: yup, I agree, is there a function to get 50% records based on values?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @MartinSmith Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Naina what's that % you"re talking about? A column in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, the `top` syntax does not do what you want.

You require a cumulative sum.  Alas, this is supported directed in SQL Server 2012, but not in SQL Server 2008.

For readability, I prefer using a correlated subquery to get the cumulative sum.  The rest of the query is just arithmetic:

```
select col1, col2, TotalCol2, CumSumCol2,
       CumSumCol2 / cast(TotalCol2 as float) as CumPercent
from (select col1, col2,
             sum(col2) over (partition by col1) as TotalCol2,
             (select sum(col2) from mytable t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <= t.col2
             ) as CumSumCol2
      from mytable t
     ) t
where CumSumCol2 / cast(TotalCol2 as float) < 0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012, you can use a window function to calculate the running sum.  The cumulative percentage is the running sum divided by the sum over the entire table.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       100.0 * sum(col2) over (order by col2) / sum(col2) over () 
                    as perc
        from    dbo.YourTable
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   perc <= 50.0
```

The subquery is required because SQL Server does not allow the use of window functions in the `where` clause.

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1c1f/2/0)

---

For older versions of SQL Server, calculating the running sum is more work.  If you have ties in `col2`, you'll have to provide a means to distinguish them.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  cur.col1
        ,       cur.col2
        ,       100.0 * sum(running.col2) / total.total as perc
        from    dbo.YourTable cur
        join    (
                select  col2
                from    dbo.YourTable prev
                ) running
        on      running.col2 < cur.col2
        cross join
                (
                select  sum(col2) as total
                from    YourTable
                ) total
        group by
                cur.col1
        ,       cur.col2      
        ,       total.total
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   perc <= 50.0
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1c1f5/1/0)

Comment: this query is throwing error "Incorrect syntax near 'order'."

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?